# Why is the keyword "is" not functioning as expected when comparing classes?

Tags: dart

I am using a redux pattern in my dart application. Inside the reducer the if statement that has the `"is"` keyword to figure out which action(in the form of a class) is being passed is not working at all.

```
DictionaryState dictionaryReducer(DictionaryState state, dynamic action){

  if(action is RequestingDictionaryEntryAction){
    // This if statement should be executed but it is not.
    return _requestingDictionaryEntry(state);
  }

  if(action is ReceivedDictionaryEntryAction){
    return _receivedDictionaryEntry(state, action);
  }

  return state;
}
```

When calling `dictionaryReducer` I am passing an action called `RequestingDictionaryEntryAction` and it is not being recognized as `RequestingDictionaryEntryAction`, instead the code continues to execute and the function does not return as it is supposed to.

Comment: The `is` operator checks whether the object is an instance of (any subclass of) the type. That works. So if you don't get the correct result, then you might have two different classes named `RequestingDictionaryEntryAction`. That can happen by accident if you import a package library using a non-`package:` URI.

Comment: Maybe `dynamic` causes that, so dart cannot deduce type in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, so don't put in too much faith, but your problem might lie in the "dynamic" type of the parameter causing the is operator to fail at compile-time. I would think it could be solved using:

```dart
DictionaryState dictionaryReducer(DictionaryState state, dynamic action){

  if(action.runtimeType == RequestingDictionaryEntryAction){
    return _requestingDictionaryEntry(state);
  }

  if(action.runtimeType == ReceivedDictionaryEntryAction){
    return _receivedDictionaryEntry(state, action);
  }

  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the argument I was passing as `action`. I was not instantiating the class properly. I was passing the class declaration itself instead of an instant of it.

`final action = RequestingDictionaryEntryAction` instead of

`final action = RequestingDictionaryEntryAction();`

:D :D